# proof of isomorphism in exact sequence and outer semi direct product

Tags: abstract-algebra

[image]
[image]

I have trouble showing why $\theta'(k,h)=\beta(k)s(h)$ is bijective between $K\rtimes_\varphi H\to G$

I tried showing the injectivity, ie. if $\beta(k)s(h)=e_G$ only if $k=e_K,h=e_H$, by showing that has to staisfy $\beta(k)=e_G,s(h)=e_g$ and $k,h$ has to be $e_K,e_H$ each.
I can show that $s(h)=e_G,$ then $\alpha(s(h))=\alpha(e_G)=e_H$, but I have trouble showing that why $k$ has to be $e_K$.

I have no much idea how to show the surjectivity.

Comment: Please do not rely on i ages to convey information not otherwise available in your posy. [See here for an explanation](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742).

Comment: You cannot establish injectivity by showing the kernel is trivial before you establish that the map is a group homomorphism.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin After showing that $\theta'$map is a gropu homomorphism, how can I show injectivity and surjectivity?
Thank you for the information that I better upload in texts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the method you suggest to check injectivity unless you have already established that $\theta'$ is a group homomorphism. I do not believe you have shown that.

To show injectivity, suppose that $\theta'(k,h) = \theta'(k',h')$. Then $\beta(k)s(h) = \beta(k')s(h')$. Therefore, since $\beta$ and $s$ *are* known to be group homomorphisms, we have:
$$\begin{align*}
\beta(k)s(h) &= \beta(k')s(h')\\
\beta(k')^{-1}\beta(k) &= s(h')s(h)^{-1}\\
\beta(k'^{-1})\beta(k) &= s(h')s(h^{-1})\\
\beta(k'^{-1}k) &= s(h'h^{-1}).
\end{align*}$$
But now, since $s$ is a section of $\alpha$, and $\mathrm{Im}(\beta)=\mathrm{ker}(\alpha)$, then applying $\alpha$ to both sides we get
$$\begin{align*}
\beta(k'^{-1}k)&=s(h'h^{-1})\\
\alpha\beta(k'^{-1}k) &= \alpha s(h'h^{-1})\\
e &= h'h^{-1}.
\end{align*}$$
Thus, $h'=h$. Then from $\beta(k)s(h) = \beta(k')s(h')$ we conclude $\beta(k)=\beta(k')$. Since $\beta$ is one-to one, we get $k=k'$. Thus, $\theta$ is one-to-one.

To show $\theta'$ is surjective, let $g\in G$, and consider $s(\alpha(g))g^{-1}$. Applying $\alpha$ we get
$$\alpha(s(\alpha(g))\alpha(g^{-1}) = \alpha(g)\alpha(g^{-1}) = e.$$
Thus, $s(\alpha(g))g^{-1}\in\mathrm{ker}(\alpha)=\mathrm{Im}(\beta)$. Taking inverses, we have $g(s\alpha(g))^{-1}\in\mathrm{Im}(\beta)$, so there exists $k\in K$ such that $g(s(\alpha(g)))^{-1} = \beta(k)$. Therefore,
$$g = \beta(k)s(\alpha(g)).$$
Hence, $g = \theta'(k,\alpha(g))$, proving that $\mathrm{Im}(\theta')=G$, as desired.

This shows bijectivity. Note we haven't shown that $\theta'$ is a group homomorphism, though.

Comment: Do we know that $\beta$ is one-to-one because it is exact sequence? I only know that it must be surjective on G if $G \to 1$

Comment: This is so cool! Thank you!

Comment: @momo Yes: the fact that it is a (short) exact sequence tells you three things: (i) the kernel of $\beta$ is the image of $1\to K$; (ii) that $\mathrm{Im}(\beta)=\ker(\alpha)$; and (iii) That $\mathrm{Im}(\alpha)=\ker(H\to 1)$. In particular, the first tells you that $\ker(\beta)=\{e_K\}$, and the last that $\mathrm{Im}(\alpha)=H$.